# Adding one more controller to resource controller in laravel5.1?

Tags: php, rest, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I am using resource controller in laravel5.1 as follows,

```
Route::resource('users', 'UserController', ['only' => ['index', 'show', 'store', 'update', 'destroy']]);
```

I would like to add two more `URL` such as active and inactive.

```
    Route::put('active', 'UserController@active');
    Route::delete('active', 'UserController@inactive');
```

It is working, but I want to implement these active and inactive in all cases such as employees,vehicles etc.

So is there any other easy method or globally adding to resource controller?

Comment: You can group the routes using Route::group

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy

```
        Route::put('users/active', [
            'as' => 'users.active.put',
            'uses' => 'UserController@active'
        ]);
        Route::delete('users/active', [
            'as' => 'users.active.delete',
            'uses' => 'UserController@inactive'
        ]);

        Route::resource('users', 'UserController', ['only' => ['index', 'show', 'store', 'update', 'destroy']]);
```

> **Remember to put your addition routes before resource because else it**
>   **will match against your show route.**